# What are the roles of ‘can’, ‘do’, and ‘is’ in ‘All a man can do is smile back’?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, modal-verbs, grammatical-roles, infinitive-constructions

What roles (Subject, Head etc) do the words *can*, *do* and *is* each play in this sentence in terms of its syntactic grammar, either individually or as a group?

1. Death **smiles** at us all, but all a man **can do is smile** back.

If we use *to* before the verb *smile*, as in:

2. Death smiles at us all, but all a man can do is **to** smile back.

Then would that make sentence (2)  ungrammatical, or would it instead somehow alter its meaning from that of sentence (1)?

Comment: Their role (function) is 'predicator'. Yes, in cases where the the subject NP contains "do" in a relative clause (as it does here), "to" can be added.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but would you say *All I can do is to eat* or *All I can do is eating*? I wouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. The man **could have been smiling**
> 2. All a man **can do is smile**

The Original Poster asks about the grammatical roles of *can*, *do* and *is* in example (2). For simplicity, I have extracted the clause we are interested in there from the larger example.

As all three of these words are verbs, it will come as no surprise that they are each heading their own verb phrase and may therefore be thought of as Heads or Predicators (a Predicator is just a special type of Head. A Head is just the main word which a larger phrase is built around, and which determines the structure of that phrase and where it occurs within larger phrases or clauses).

However, knowing that *can*, *do* and *is* in (2) are all Heads of verb phrases really only tells us a very little bit about their 'grammatical role' within the larger sentence. It tells us about their place in the structure of the immediate chunk of words that that verb occurs in and nothing else. And really, we could take any word of category 'X' and ask "What is the grammatical function of this word?" and the answer would nearly always be 'Head of an X phrase.' If you really want to know about the structural role played by a word, you need to also think about what job that phrase is doing in the larger sentence.

In example (1) you will see a string of four verbs in bold. Each of these verbs has a special relationship specifically with the verb that precedes or follows it. To start off with, the modal verb *could* heads the verb phrase:

3. could have been smiling

It takes as its Complement another verb phrase headed by the auxiliary verb *have*:

4. have been smiling

The verb *have* here takes as its complement another verb phrase headed by the verb *been*:

5. been smiling

And of course within this verb phrase we see the auxiliary verb *been* taking a verb phrase headed by the present participle *smiling* (a one-word verb phrase in its own right).

So in (1) we see a chain or *catenation* of verbs and verb phrases where one verb takes a phrase headed by another verb, which takes a phrase headed by another verb, to give one large verb phrase within which successive verb phrases are nested:

6. The man [could [have [been [smiling]]]].

In (6) above, the verbs *could*, *have*, *been* and *smiling* are all Heads of their own verb phrases.  However, their arrangement and structure are very different indeed from those of the verbs *can, do is* and *smile* in (2).

### **All-clefts**

Clauses such as the one in (2), reproduced here as example (7) are sometimes referred to as *all*-clefts:

7. All (that) a man can do is smile.

*All*-clefts have three notable features: a noun phrase Subject consisting of the determiner *all* modified by an integrated relative clause; some form of the verb *be* used as a copula verb in its specifying sense; a phrase functioning as Predicative Complement of the verb *be*.

Notice then that in this sentence the verb *can* heads the verb phrase *can do* which appears inside the relative clause *a man can do*, which in turn appears within the subject noun phrase *all (that) a man can do.*

The following verb *is* is not a Complement of the verb *can* or the verb *do* but instead heads the verb phrase *is smile* which functions as the Predicate of the matrix clause (the main clause). It therefore occurs in a completely different constituent (a different chunk of words) from the preceding verbs. Structurally, it is arguably the most important word in the whole sentence.

Lastly we turn to the verb *smile.* Although this verb occurs as the Complement of the verb *be* here, the two verbs do not form part of an aspectual construction or a passive. *Smile* is not the Catenative Complement of *is*. In (1) we saw the verb phrase *been smiling*, where the *-ing* form *smiling* was mandatory because of the verb *been.* In other words, the verb *be* dictated the form of the  verb. We could not have used a plain form of the verb, *smile*, for example:

8. *could have been smile (ungrammatical)

In the verb phrase *is smile*, however, the form of the verb *smile* does **not** depend on the verb *is*. When *be* is used in its specifying sense as a copular verb, it does not put restrictions on any verb it takes as a Complement. In such constructions it is the Subject, in fact, which determines the form of verb functioning as Predicative Complement. Consider:

9. [All he is do**ing**] is [smil**ing**].

### **Executive summary**

In the example:

- all a man can do is smile

... the verbs *can, do* and *is* are not part of the same verb phrase. They do not form a constituent. In fact *can* and *do* occur within a relative clause within the Subject, whereas *is* is the Head verb in the verb phrase forming the Predicate.

Within the relative clause in the subject, *can* is the Head of the Predicate. It takes a smaller verb phrase headed by *do* as its Complement.

Incidentally, the verb *smile*, which occurs as Complement of the verb *is*, is not a Catenative Complement, but a Predicative one. Thus although it occurs as a Complement of the verb, its form is actually dependent on the form of the Subject noun phrase, not the Head verb.

Comment: +1 as usual. A succinct summary of one sample of a very complex construction type. It's always the short sentences that cause the most trouble, because all the instructions and labels are left off; they they complain because it doesn't match what they were taught in "grammar school". Oy.

Comment: There's still the small matter of what licenses using *smile back* without a *to* here, but I don't know what exactly he doesn't know. Maybe his question is whether it's for the same reason as you can with *His grin made me smile back*, or whether something else is in play, like maybe a holdover from the modal *can* somehow applying to more than one verb. *What you can do is smile back* unclefts oddly: *Smile back is what you can do*. It's perhaps easier with *The suggestion is ((for you) to) smile back*, producing *?Smile back is the suggestion* or *For you to smile back is the suggestion.*

Comment: @tchrist Do you mean you can leave out _to_ in _The suggestion is to smile back_?

Comment: If the Subject determines the form of verb functioning as Predicative Complement, why is the correct form _smile_, not _smiled_, in the following sentence? _All he has done is smile/*smiled._

Comment: @JK2 Those are both grammatical for me. When there is no gerund-participle involved, the form of the VP complement of *be*, it seems to me, can be dictated either by the pro-verb *do*, or by the auxiliary which takes it as a complement. So here *smiled* is ok, determined by *has* and *smile* is ok, determined by *do*. I think.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him You're right. Here's a counterexample, though: _All he did is smile._, where you can't substitute the past tense _smiled_ for the infinitive _smile_ and say *_All he did is smiled._

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Is "All he has done" a variant of "What he has done"?

Comment: @user424874 Not exactly,  but they are very similar--as you've noticed.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Thanks. I found this example from CoGEL: "(?) What he’s done is spoilt the whole thing. " Their comment: "This last type is, however, of doubtful acceptability, and instances of it may indeed be interpreted as ellipted forms of an alternative construction involving apposition :  What he's done is ((this): he's) spoilt the whole thing. " I just thought that one is relevant since you said "All he has done is smile/smiled." is okay.

Comment: @user424874 Do you have the p. no?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Sure. page 1388.

Comment: @user424874 Interesting. Don't think I agree with their grammaticality judgement! Certainly not with their alternative reformulation. Why, exactly? Because it applies to their other examples too: i.e. "What I am doing is [this: I'm] teaching him a lesson"

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I'm happy you find that interesting.  I think I get what you mean. But just want to check my understanding, when you said "In such constructions it is the Subject, in fact, which determines the form of verb functioning as Predicative Complement" do you mean "All he did is smiled" (JK2's example) is okay? Or only the "(to) smile" is grammatical?

Comment: @user424874 For me only the '(to) smile' version works, but note that that's still determined by the subject!

Comment: @Araucaria-Him thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him How does the subject determine the form of verb functioning as Predicative Complement in _All he did is smile._?

Comment: @JK2 Well, it's not being dictated by *is*, or licensed by *is* that's for sure - no brainer there. If there was an *-ing* verb in the subject, we'd be able to have an *-ing* form as the PC. No *-ing* form in the subject, no *-ing* form in the PC. QED, the form of the subject dictates the permissible forms in the PC.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ answered:

> Their role (function) is 'predicator'. Yes, in cases where the the subject NP contains "do" in a relative clause (as it does here), "to" can be added.

Comment: Well, yes they’re predicators but of wildly different VPs! For example the ‘do’ VP  is inside the’ an’ one, whereas the ‘is’ one most certainly isn’t!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I wouldn't worry about it. The OP talks about "roles", which means they're playing with a different deck than either of us or BillJ. They want somebody to explain what their teacher didn't.